How to batch process a large number of geometric shapes using QGIS?
Could you please help me solve how to batch process a large number of geometric shapes using QGIS?
The geometric shapes in the layer are offset from their correct positions, and I need to adjust them one by one. The shape does not need to be changed, but the position of the shapes needs to be changed. There are thousands of such shapes in my layer. Do you know how to quickly adjust these offset shapes to their correct positions? My layer has four fields, namely id, geome, xqid, update_date. update_date is the time when null becomes saved every time the graphic is manually moved to the correct position and saved.


I have tried writing some code in the Python console of QGIS using the QGsProduct module, but I am not sure how to get started. This is my first time using this tool.
Please tell me in detail how to quickly complete these tasks?

If I understood correctly, you need to programmatically adjust the positions of the geometries inside a QGIS layer and update an attribute field to record when the change occurs. Below is a Python script that should accomplish this. I defined a function (adjust_position) which translates each geometry and updates the 'update_date' field. This function is invoked for every feature in the specified layer, then the layer is updated. Be sure to replace 'your_layer_name' with the actual name of your layer and adjust the translation values as necessary.
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from datetime import datetime

def adjust_position(feature):
    geom = feature.geometry()
    geom.translate(-100, -50)  # Adjust these values as needed
    feature.setGeometry(geom)    
    feature['update_date'] = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return feature

layer_name = 'your_layer_name'
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)

if layers:
    layer = layers[0]
    layer.startEditing()
    
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        corrected_feature = adjust_position(feature)
        layer.updateFeature(corrected_feature)

    layer.commitChanges()

